# C++ ifstream of image file

Tags: c++, image, fstream

I am having trouble reading image file into a buffer. When I read normal ascii file, everything is fine and dandy, but when it comes to image file I suspect there is a \0 character inside an image file?

I needed to take in image file, parsed it into 16KB blocks for hashing, but when I do

```
 std::ifstream ifs;
 ifs.open(file_name, std::ifstream::binary | std::ifstream::in);
 .     
 .
 .
 std::string block;
 char buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
 .
 .
 .
 memset(buffer, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
 ifs.read(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE);
 block = buffer;

 std::cout << i << " | block size: " << block.length() 
           << " | buffer size: " << strlen(buffer) << std::endl;

 hash = sha256(block); // string type required for openssl's function
```

I get

```
0 | block size: 4 | buffer size: 4
1 | block size: 16 | buffer size: 16
2 | block size: 88 | buffer size: 88
3 | block size: 57 | buffer size: 57
4 | block size: 109 | buffer size: 109
5 | block size: 26 | buffer size: 26
6 | block size: 65 | buffer size: 65
```

How do I resolve this issue? I am suspecting, for example

```
junkjunkjunk\0junkjunkjunk
```

that the image file have random \0

Comment: _" I suspect there is a \0 character inside an image file?"_ That shouldn't matter as long you're using `ifs.read(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE);`

Comment: What types are `block` and `buffer`?

Comment: Then how come the length of the block is less than the expected block size? I am guessing that length() stops when it encounters a null character?

Comment: @Galik, block is string type, buffer is char array

Comment: You are not doing a string operation so you should not use string types and operations. You should use types and the operations can be used for the buffers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `strlen()` to get length of binary data, because it is for obtaining length of null-terminated C-style string. Assigning the binary data using `=` operator to `std::string` is also a bad idea.

You can use function [`std::istream::gcount()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/gcount/) to obtain length that is read by last `read()` or other unformatted input operation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

int main(){
    const int BLOCK_SIZE = 16 * 1024;
    const char* file_name = "test.dat";
    int i = 0;
    std::ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(file_name, std::ifstream::binary | std::ifstream::in);

    char buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];

    memset(buffer, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
    ifs.read(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE);

    std::cout << i << " | buffer size: " << ifs.gcount() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, needed the length because of the len in `SHA256_Update(SHA256_CTX *context, const uint8_t *data, size_t len);`
`

Answer (score 1):

If `block` is a `std::string` try using the returned length like this:

```
std::string block;
char buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];

ifs.read(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE);

// check for errors here

block.assign(buffer, ifs.gcount());
```

The function `ifs.gcount()` returns the number of characters that were read.

Using `block = buffer` forces the string to detect the end of the data by looking for a null character. This is appropriate for null terminated c-style strings but not strings (or data) in general.